The .docx file modified using 'docx' module on opening shows "The open office xml file cannot be opened because there are problem with contents"
I am using docx module to modify a word file. It works well for inserting a text, paragraph, link, etc. But breaks on inserting a table. It shows the error "The open office xml file cannot be opened because there are problem with contents".
Note: File shows error while opening it in Microsoft word, but it works while showing preview of the file and also for converting the docx file to pdf(I can saw the table in pdf file). I am using "docx-preview" module to show the preview.
Thanks.
I am expecting the modified word(docx) file to open in the Microsoft Word as well.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
